# What is "posted" in ASP.NET MVC applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, post

As I review more code and blog posts from lots of MVC sources, I still haven't wrapped my mind around what is "posted" when a request is made. I realize MVC doesn't support post, but I'm having trouble finding resources that can explain it well enough to understand.

Inside the controller's `public ActionResult nameOfAction(what the heck goes here?) { ... }` what are my parameters?

Sometimes it looks like Visual Studio scaffolds `(int id, MyObject myobject)` for an Edit-style action--it includes something from my model, but not always.

Sometimes, it's `(int id, FormCollection collection)` for a delete-style action. Why not use the modeled object here? Is a FormCollection object always "posted"?

Sometimes, I see `(RouteInfo routeInfo)` which isn't recognized in my MVC2 Intellisense (is this MVC1 only or something?)

How can/do/should I establish these parameters? I think this will help me a lot at design time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What gets post back from a form in MVC is the form data which includes each form element in a keyvalue pair.

If you only need this information then you would use:

```
public ActionResult nameOfAction(string name, string lastName, string etc)
```

MVC has some smart data model binding which takes the form data and automatically creates an object which is part of you domain model. For instance it could automatically create a Person object with the provided form data.

I believe there is a security concern with this as a user of your site may post data which is not part of your form and guess what your models are to inject their own data. 
I dont think this is a massive issue though and this is the way I would go.

I think you can use the anti-forgery helper to prevent users from posting back data which is not allowed in a form. [anti-forgery](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/05/22/anti-forgery-request-recipes-for-asp-net-mvc-and-ajax.aspx)

Comment: I am assuming name, lastName, and etc are all ID's of some kind of input element? So, I can use just the field ID's I need, or the `FormCollection` object to avoid excessive naming of parameters in the signature of the method?

Answer (score 1):

Use strongly typed views with a view-model and the strongly typed helpers. Then when you POST, you should get an instance of that view-model out.

Comment: What if I'm not always using a strongly-typed view? I don't necessarily see why I wouldn't, but why does the default Delete method use a FormCollection and not a MyObject as a paramter? And is there some MVC2 equivalent to RouteInfo?

Comment: The form collection is just just one way of representing the data with out model binding. I'm not sure how well model binding works without strongly typed views.

Comment: How would the data coming into the view ensure you are getting strongly typed data out of the view?